# apply a function to a nested list

Tags: r

I have already post a very similar question but the situation has changed and the answer that I got is not valid for these "new characteristics"

**Older post:**

I am wondering if it is possible to apply a function in different levels of a nested list, `rapply` applies a function recursively in a list but in the same level. My question is related to apply a function in different levels with different lengths. An example for illustration:

```
list <- list(list(a=1:5, b=5:9, c=6:10, d=1:5),
             list(e=2:6, f=3:7, g=8:12),
             list(h=3:7, i=6:10, j=11:15, k=2:6),
             list(l=4:8, m=2:6),
             list(n=5:9, o=1:5, p=2:6, q=0:4),
             list(r=6:10, s=3:7, t=9:13))
```

I would like to apply a function, such as `sum`, to the first elements (e.g `[[1]]$a=1, [[1]]$b=5, [[1]]$c=6, [[1]]d=1`, then to the second ones (e.g `[[1]]$a=2, [[1]]$b=6, [[1]]$c=7, [[1]]$d=2)` and so on. The result should be something like that:

```
[[1]]
13 17 21 25 29

[[2]]
13 16 19 22 25

[[3]]
22 26 30 34 38

[[4]]
6 8 10 12 14

[[5]]
8 12 16 20 24

[[6]]
18 21 24 27 30
```

Perhaps a combination of `rapply` and `mapply`?

Thanks

***New post*:**

@G.Grothendieck already gave me a good solution for this chase however, I have other list with pvalues where I would like to apply more complex functions, e.g. `mean` or other functions such as:

```
Fisher.test <- function(p) {
  Xsq <- -2*sum(log(p))
  p.val <- 1-pchisq(Xsq, df = 2*length(p))
  return(p.val)
}
```

Reduce does not work as it does with functions like `sum` or with `f="+"`, any suggestions??

Here is an example how this new list looks like"

```
pval.list <- list(list(a=c(0.05, 0.0001, 0.32, 0.45), b=c(0.1,0.12,0.01,0.06), c=c(0.1,0.12,0.01,0.06), d=c(0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04)),
             list(e=c(0.04, 0.1, 0.232, 0.245), f=c(0.05, 0.01, 0.22, 0.54), g=c(0.005, 0.1, 0.032, 0.045)),
             list(h=c(0.03, 0.01, 0.12, 0.4), i=c(0.5, 0.0001, 0.132, 0.045), j=c(0.005, 0.0001, 0.0032, 0.045), k=c(0.5, 0.1, 0.932, 0.545)),
             list(l=c(0.022, 0.0012, 0.32, 0.45), m=c(0.0589, 0.0001, 0.0032, 0.0045)),
             list(n=c(0.051, 0.01, 0.32, 0.45), o=c(0.05, 0.0001, 0.32, 0.45), p=c(0.05, 0.0001, 0.32, 0.45), q=c(0.05, 0.0001, 0.32, 0.45)),
             list(r=c(0.053, 0.001, 0.32, 0.45), s=c(0.05, 0.0001, 0.32, 0.45), t=c(0.05, 0.0001, 0.32, 0.45)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `Reduce` cannot be applied directly with `Fisher.test` it can be applied with `cbind` and then `Fisher.test` can be applied to that:

```
> lapply(lapply(pval.list, Reduce, f = cbind), apply, 1, Fisher.test)
[[1]]
[1] 1.953968e-03 2.999509e-05 5.320831e-04 1.339104e-02

[[2]]
[1] 0.0007878665 0.0052625525 0.0457435481 0.1146067577

[[3]]
[1] 8.982382e-03 3.055250e-08 1.064109e-02 5.094879e-02

[[4]]
[1] 9.911091e-03 2.032293e-06 8.073256e-03 1.458443e-02

[[5]]
[1] 2.357950e-03 6.135981e-11 3.326486e-01 6.038488e-01

[[6]]
[1] 6.597414e-03 3.470933e-09 3.362226e-01 5.708789e-01
```

ADDED:

This can be slightly shortened using `simplify2array` like this:

```
lapply(lapply(pval.list, simplify2array), apply, 1, Fisher.test)
```

or using `data.frame` like this:

```
lapply(lapply(pval.list, data.frame), apply, 1, Fisher.test)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
lapply(pval.list, function(x){apply(do.call(rbind, x), 2, Fisher.test)})
[[1]]
[1] 1.953968e-03 2.999509e-05 5.320831e-04 1.339104e-02

[[2]]
[1] 0.0007878665 0.0052625525 0.0457435481 0.1146067577

[[3]]
[1] 8.982382e-03 3.055250e-08 1.064109e-02 5.094879e-02

[[4]]
[1] 9.911091e-03 2.032293e-06 8.073256e-03 1.458443e-02

[[5]]
[1] 2.357950e-03 6.135981e-11 3.326486e-01 6.038488e-01

[[6]]
[1] 6.597414e-03 3.470933e-09 3.362226e-01 5.708789e-01
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the following work for you?

My solutions uses nested `lapply`

**1.**

```
lapply(lapply(list, function(l)do.call(rbind, l)), colSums)
```

**2.**

```
lapply(lapply(pval.list, function(l)do.call(rbind, l)), apply, 2, Fisher.test )
```

Comment: your approach similar to this one proposed by user1609452 works perfectly, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can be done even quicker with the `plyr` package, but the following works well. First make a new list in which the inner lists are converted to matrices

```
new.pval.list <- vector('list', length(pval.list))
for (i in 1:length(pval.list)) {
  nc <- length(unlist(pval.list[[i]] [1]))
  new.pval.list [[i]] <- matrix(unlist(pval.list[[i]]), ncol = nc, byrow = T)
}
```

We can use the apply function to each element of the new list with the matrices

```
lapply(new.pval.list, function(mat) apply(mat, 2, Fisher.test))
```

Comment: I got the following error: `Error in apply(mat, 2, Fisher.test) : dim(X) must have a positive length`